# Magento Cart Price Rule - How to Sum Specific Category For Discount

Tags: magento2, category, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, tiered-pricing

I want to create a discount code in Magento 2. The offer is £25 off every £250 spent on Garden Furniture.

So, the rules must only apply on products from the garden category in the cart. For example, a customer may have £525 of garden furniture category in their cart, as well as £300 from other categories. In this case, they would get £50 off.

I have several rules set up for each discount tier, i.e. 250-499.99, 500-749.99, etc.

I am only able to get the cart price rule to detect that something from garden is in the cart, but it sums the entire cart and applies the discount, i.e. a customer could have a £50 garden table, but £700 of other furniture, and get £75 off, since they have £750 worth of goods and one of them in garden.

Is there a way I can get the cart price rule to only sum the total cart value of specified categories?

TIA :)

Comment: Please check this link https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-create.html

Comment: When choosing a product subselection based on category, the only cart rules that follow are 'cart item rules' - none of these sum the value of various cart rows of a specified product category

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim for https://stackoverflow.com/a/28336670/1307623

Can you try by this way

If ALL of these conditions are TRUE :

If **total amount** **equals or greater** than 100 for a subselection of items in cart matching **ALL** of these conditions:

Category **contains** 145

Note: if you have product prices as included VAT in website then adjust the value accordingly

magento reference in below image
[image]